# Invoking MSYS bash from Windows cmd

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, msys

I'm using GCC on Windows 7 (using the TDM's build). I installed MSYS to be able to execute [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) and compile using makefiles. However, it is tedious to every time start up the MSYS [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) shell, navigate to the directory of the project and run `make`.

What I want is to automate this process. I prefer to have a batch file in Windows, or something similar, from which I then invoke the MSYS Bash shell. It should navigate to the directory the batch file resides in and call `make`.

Is this possible? Can I send commands to MSYS Bash from cmd (like navigation/invoking `make`)? Or can I let the MSYS Bash run a "Bash script", which sets the commands to be executed much like batch scripts?

PS: This is something similar to Stack Overflow question *[Executing MSYS from cmd.exe with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546757)*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not an MSYS expert, but does something like this work for you:

```
rem Call this something like compile-project.bat
c:
cd \src\project
bash -c "make"
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to use bash to execute make, or any of the other MSYS programs. If you put the MSYS bin directory on your path, you can execute them from a Windows command shell. Alternatively, the bash shell has an enormously powerful scripting language built in.  But I'm not clear if that's what you are asking about - you should clarify your question with an actual example of what you want to do, spelling out the steps you want automated.

My own setup is to have a Windows Explorer context menu called "Bash here" which opens a bash shell in the directory I select. This is done via the following registry entries:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mybash]
@="Bash Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mybash\command]
@="cmd /c c:\\bash.cmd %1"
```

And the following bash.cmd file in c::

```
@echo off
title bash
cd %1%
bash
```

Note that the MSYS bin directory is on my path. And of course, any registry hacking is at your own risk.

Comment: This works great, though I needed to use /k instead of /c for the console to stay open.

Answer (score 3):

Just add executables to your Windows PATH:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
C:\msys64\usr\bin
```

Keep in mind, this adds a lot of executables to your path which might conflict with other applications. The `..\usr\bin` directory contains all installed MSYS2 packages. There is a lot of unnecessary stuff. `..mingw64\bin` directory has a smaller list.

[Source](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/install-gcc-compiler-windows-msys2-cc)

Comment: would not recommend this, unless you make a mess of your current env

Answer (score 2):

On my `MSYS-1.0.11` with the MSYS developers packages, I can call a bash script (`CurrentScript.sh`) with a cmd/bat file in the current folder with this command:

```
R:\MinGW\MSYS-1.0.11\bin\sh "%cd%\CurrentScript.sh"
```