# pkg-config as command line argument in cmd windows 10 back quote problem

Tags: gcc, cmd, windows-10, gtk3, pkg-config

### Problem description:

I am using [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) OS and from the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window I can use [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) compiler:

```
gcc --version
```

returns:

> ```
> gcc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0
> Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> ```

I want to use GTK+ for creating GUIs and therefore installed GTK+ library using MSYS2. When compiling a small program I need to use `pkg-config` in back quotes symbols:

```
gcc -o first_test ../gd_src/first_test.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

### Problem:

The `gcc` compiler throws the following error:

> ```
> gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
> ```

However, just typing:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

returns:

> ```
> -pthread -mms-bitfields -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
> ```

I should also point out that using MSYS2 provided cmd window (I do not know how to call it, bash ... ?) there is no such problem.

### My opinion

I guess is some kind of problem with backquote in the cmd window for Windows 10 ?! How can I solve this?

### update

Just running

```
gcc -o first_test ../gd_src/first_test.c pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

gives:

> ```
> gcc: error: pkg-config: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: gtk+-3.0: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
> ```

Comment: C Marius, I have attempted to format your code and output as you had intended it. Can you please take a look to see if it has been done accurately. Can you please also explain why you need to use back ticks, as it appears from your output that not using them is correct.

Comment: Also please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2546757) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546842), and see if it helps to solve your issue.

Comment: @Compo Unfortunately not using them, I get the same sort of complaints from the gcc, as can be seen from my updated question ...